# Debugging spring-cloud-sleuth for HTTP 400

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using spring-cloud-sleuth:2.0.1.RELEASE with Spring Webflux.
When I use curl to send a request to my service, I see the logs like the below indicating trace & span IDs are generated.

```
18:13:23.739 [reactor-http-nio-5] DEBUG o.s.c.s.i.w.TraceWebFilter - Found span in context RealSpan(9c06fd39895e2ee3/5dba1ae22704d24c)

18:13:23.739 [reactor-http-nio-5] DEBUG o.s.c.s.i.w.TraceWebFilter - Handled send of RealSpan(9c06fd39895e2ee3/5dba1ae22704d24c)
```

But when I use extra request headers like below, I get back "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"

```
-H 'X─B3─TraceId: d5852998fd23ef53' -H 'X─B3─SpanId: c37d6d4249e0f0bd' -H 'X-B3-Flags: 1' -H 'X─B3─ParentSpanId :c37d6d4249e0f0xx' -H 'X-B3-Sampled: 1'
```

I already have debug turned on for org.springframework.cloud.sleuth and brave. But I am not getting any error logs when I get back HTTP 400. How do I debug this issue?

Comment: Maybe turn on debug logs for spring?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak , the reason for failure was bad characters in the curl request :(